# How to Stream Discussions in Facebook Group

Tags: facebook

Anybody have Idea on how to stream contents from my facebook open group to my personal web page.
Any widgets? I tried comments widget but it streams only the posts made through the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no social plugin to do this but you could create an app which reads the groups posts and displayed them on your web site. You would need to auth the user of your website and request the user_groups permission for them. Their access token can then be used to show them the group's contents by calling the feed connection on the group object detailed here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Example: https://graph.facebook.com//feed?access_token=